# What does this method do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is actually in a Rails helper that I've seen. I see it's trying to create a hash from names, which appears to be anything that includes the Enumerable module. It's creating a hash of keys.. but where is the binding coming from? how do you pass it one? and what is happening with eval(key, binding)?

```
  def locals_hash(names, binding)
    names.inject({}) {|memo, key| memo[key.to_sym] = eval(key, binding); memo}
  end
```

Comment: Have you seen the docs for `eval` and `binding`?  http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005922

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ken's comment, here's an example:

```
def locals_hash(names, binding)
  names.inject({}) {|memo, key| memo[key.to_sym] = eval(key, binding); memo}
end

def m
  a = 3
  b = 'foo'
  binding
end

locals_hash ['a', 'b'], m
#=> {:a=>3, :b=>"foo"}
```